# What is the Google Chrome equivalent to Firebug?

Tags: development, performance, google-chrome, profiling

I'm looking for a tool that can:

- inspect HTML elements
- manage/debug JavaScript
- profile performance
- modify elements in real-time

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's built in. Page [paper] -> Developer -> Developer tools (in Chrome v5 and under). It is likely to be different in v6 since the Page button appears to be disappearing in that version.

Comment: There are some drawbacks to Google's tool -- viewing ajax requests is not as easy, there's no multiline mode that's convenient, you can't edit HTML in a window, it doesn't show the padding/margins on hover in the HTML tree, you simply can't navigate the actual DOM (just the HTML tree) and last but not least, I find the CSS editing features just clunkier -- there's no autocomplete in Google's for one thing. It's still very much usable, but Firebug is just better.

Comment: Or shift-ctrl-I for the lazy :)

Comment: @Mark Note, I'm using 5.0.375.99. I'm not sure if it makes a difference now or in the future though.

Comment: In v6 it's Wrench -> Tools -> Developer Tools

Answer (score 17):

Right-Click -> Inspect Element

Answer (score 13):

[Firebug Lite for Google Chrome](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/).

Comment: FireBug Lite is a great tool and also works in IE, Opera, Safari and Firefox: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 6):

It's been 4 years since the original question was asked. Chrome (stable) is now at version 38. For a long time it has included a full set of [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) that are roughly equivalent to Firebug for Firefox (though incidentally Firefox even has a [built-in inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) too).

A few things Chrome's Developer Tools allow you to do:

- Inspect the DOM
- Inspect CSS
- Access a JavaScript Console
- Debug JavaScript
- View network requests, timings, and responses
- View rendering, JavaScript, and CSS performance
- Inspect local storage and cookies

The dev tools can be accessed in a variety of ways.

- **Chrome Menu** -> **Tools** -> **Developer Tools**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on a Mac
- <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows
- Right-click anywhere on a page and select **Inspect Element**

Answer (score 3):

The in-browser tools are great at their job and are usually your best first choice, but sometimes they don't provide enough technical detail on the HTTP request/response payloads, or are too page-specific.

In these cases, you may find that a dedicated HTTP inspection tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or one of the [Linux alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2) will provide more insight.

If you really need to get bare-metal, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) goes beyond HTTP to full network traffic analysis, but be prepared to be overwhelmed at first.

Comment: I can't say that I'm familiar with fiddler but Wireshark is definitely excessively bare-metal. Wireshark is really only useful if you need to see the lower level protocols details.

Comment: Fiddler is closer to firebug / chrome developer tools for usability.  One of the places I've found it most handy is when publishing KML files on my website; you can see the requests and responses from Windows desktop applications like Google Earth, not just web browsers.  I've used Wireshark a couple times, but agree that it isn't generally useful for day-to-day webmaster stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Google's open source Speed Tracer - http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/

> Speed Tracer is a tool to help you
>   identify and fix performance problems
>   in your web applications. It
>   visualizes metrics that are taken from
>   low level instrumentation points
>   inside of the browser and analyzes
>   them as your application runs. Speed
>   Tracer is available as a Chrome
>   extension and works on all platforms
>   where extensions are currently
>   supported (Windows and Linux).
>
> Using Speed Tracer you are able to get
>   a better picture of where time is
>   being spent in your application. This
>   includes problems caused by JavaScript
>   parsing and execution, layout, CSS
>   style recalculation and selector
>   matching, DOM event handling, network
>   resource loading, timer fires,
>   XMLHttpRequest callbacks, painting,
>   and more.