# inspect element on webpage displayed by Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How can I inspect an element within a webpage displayed by Google Chrome browser as Firebug allows me to do on Firefox ?  
This [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-is-the-google-chrome-equivalent-to-firebug) does not help me.
If you are used to use Firefox and Firebug, you can see what I am looking for on this picture (circled in red color):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't offer this functionality but you can right click on the element you wish to inspect and choose `Inspect Element`. The results will be the same.